# React проблемы с модальным окном и массивом

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, redux, modal

Я использую состояние все работает нормально, за исключением модального окна. Внутри состояния, я использую объекты, которые нормально отображаются (вы можете посмотреть на скриншот https://ibb.co/YBg30NW ) пожалуйста,обратите внимание на кнопки под названием "Открытый модал", когда вы нажмете на одну их этих кнопок, модальное окно открывается и должны отображать название языка программирования, как показано на скриншоте. Проблема в том, что при открытии модального окна отображается только одно и то же название языков программирования "CSS" https://ibb.co/J5jrZF0 независимо от того, какую кнопку я нажимаю, чтобы открыть модальное окно, отображается только "CSS", как я могу решить эту проблему?

```
 import React from "react"
    import cnStyle from "./ContentCourses.module.css"
    import python from "./Icons/pyhton.png"
    import cPlusPlus from "./Icons/c++.png"
    import JavaScript from "./Icons/JavaScript.png"
    import swift from "./Icons/swift.png"
    import HTML from "./Icons/HTML.png"
    import CSS from "./Icons/CSS.png"
    import Modal from 'react-modal';
    
    const customStyles = {
        content: {
            top: '50%',
            left: '50%',
            right: 'auto',
            bottom: 'auto',
            marginRight: '-50%',
            transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
        }
    };
    
    Modal.setAppElement('#root');
    
    export class ContentCourses extends React.Component {
    
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                languageInfo: [
                    {
                        languageName: "Python 3",
                        about: `
                        Learn Python, one of today's most in-demand programming languages on-the-go!
                        Practice writing Python code, collect points, & show off your skills now!`,
                        Learners: 30045,
                        Lessons: 87,
                        Quizzes: 271,
                        icon: python,
                    },
    
                    {
                        languageName: "JavaScript",
                        about: `
                        Learn all the basic features of JavaScript, including making your website more interactive,
                        changing website content, validating forms, and so much more.`,
                        Learners: 42123,
                        Lessons: 42,
                        Quizzes: 321,
                        icon: JavaScript,
                    },
    
                    {
                        languageName: "C++",
                        about: `
                        Our C++ tutorial covers basic concepts, data types, arrays, pointers, conditional statements,
                        loops, functions, classes, objects, inheritance, and polymorphism.`,
                        Learners: 53241,
                        Lessons: 23,
                        Quizzes: 451,
                        icon: cPlusPlus,
                    },
    
                    {
                        languageName: "Swift",
                        about: `
                        Learn all the main concepts of Swift programming and apply your newly gained knowledge
                        to create your own, fully functioning iOS app!`,
                        Learners: 63211,
                        Lessons: 54,
                        Quizzes: 623,
                        icon: swift,
                    },
    
                    {
                        languageName: "HTML",
                        about: `
                        This FREE course will teach you how to design a web page using HTML.
                        Complete a series of hands-on exercises and practice while writing real HTML code.`,
                        Learners: 18024,
                        Lessons: 32,
                        Quizzes: 962,
                        icon: HTML,
                    },
    
                    {
                        languageName: "CSS",
                        about: `
                        Our CSS course will teach you how to control the style & layout of websites.
                        Complete a series of exercises and practice while filling out actual CSS templates.`,
                        Learners: 58932,
                        Lessons: 46,
                        Quizzes: 125,
                        icon: CSS,
                    },
    
                ],
    
                modalIsOpen: false,
                setIsOpen: false,
            }
        }
    
        openModal() {
            this.setState({setIsOpen: true})
            this.setState({modalIsOpen: true})
        }
    
        afterOpenModal() {
            // references are now sync'd and can be accessed.
            // subtitle.style.color = '#f00';
        }
    
        closeModal() {
            this.setState({setIsOpen: false})
            this.setState({modalIsOpen: false})
        }
    
        render() {
            var subtitle;
            const resultsRender = [];
    
            for (var i = 0; i < this.state.languageInfo.length; i += 2) {
                resultsRender.push(
                    <div className={cnStyle.clearfix}>
                        {
                            this.state.languageInfo.slice(i, i + 2).map((item, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div key={index} className={cnStyle.ContentVeryHeadlineBlock}>
    
                                            <div className={cnStyle.ContentHeadlineBlock}>
                                                <div className={cnStyle.ContentCoursesBlock}>
    
                                                    <div style={{marginRight: '25px'}} className={cnStyle.courseIconBlock}>
                                                        <img className={cnStyle.courseIcon} src={item.icon} alt=""/>
                                                    </div>
    
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div className={cnStyle.courseName}>
                                                            <h3>{item.languageName}</h3>
                                                        </div>
    
                                                        <div>
                                                            <p style={{color: 'dimgrey'}}>
                                                                {item.about}
                                                            </p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
    
    
                                                <div className={cnStyle.buttonMoreBlock}>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <button onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)}>Open Modal</button>
                                                        <Modal
                                                            isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                                                            onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal.bind(this)}
                                                            onRequestClose={this.closeModal.bind(this)}
                                                            style={customStyles}
                                                            contentLabel="Example Modal"
                                                        >
    
                                                            <h2 ref={_subtitle => (subtitle = _subtitle)}>{item.languageName}</h2>
                                                            <button onClick={this.closeModal.bind(this)}>close</button>
                                                            <div>I am a modal</div>
                                                            <form>
                                                                <input />
                                                                <button>tab navigation</button>
                                                                <button>stays</button>
                                                                <button>inside</button>
                                                                <button>the modal</button>
                                                            </form>
                                                        </Modal>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
    
                                            </div>
    
                                            <div className={cnStyle.moreInformation}>
                                                <div>
                                                    <p>Learners</p>
                                                    <p className={cnStyle.learnQuantity}>{item.Learners}</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <p>Lessons</p>
                                                    <p className={cnStyle.learnQuantity}>{item.Lessons}</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <p>Quizzes</p>
                                                    <p className={cnStyle.learnQuantity}>{item.Quizzes}</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    );
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    </div>
                );
            }
    
            return (
                <div>
                    {resultsRender}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас общее состояние для всех окон, они все одновременно открываются и закрываются (последний перекрывает все предыдущие). Нужно каждому разделу дать свои флаги на состояние модального окна.

```
export class ContentCourses extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            languageInfo: [
                {
                    id:"1",
                    languageName: "Python 3",
                    about: `
                    Learn Python, one of today's most in-demand programming languages on-the-go!
                    Practice writing Python code, collect points, & show off your skills now!`,
                    Learners: 30045,
                    Lessons: 87,
                    Quizzes: 271,
                    modalIsOpen: false,
                    setIsOpen:false,
                },

                {
                    id:"2",
                    languageName: "JavaScript",
                    about: `
                    Learn all the basic features of JavaScript, including making your website more interactive,
                    changing website content, validating forms, and so much more.`,
                    Learners: 42123,
                    Lessons: 42,
                    Quizzes: 321,
                    modalIsOpen: false,
                    setIsOpen:false,
                },

                {
                    id:"3",
                    languageName: "C++",
                    about: `
                    Our C++ tutorial covers basic concepts, data types, arrays, pointers, conditional statements,
                    loops, functions, classes, objects, inheritance, and polymorphism.`,
                    Learners: 53241,
                    Lessons: 23,
                    Quizzes: 451,
                    modalIsOpen: false,
                    setIsOpen:false,
                },

                {
                    id:"4",
                    languageName: "Swift",
                    about: `
                    Learn all the main concepts of Swift programming and apply your newly gained knowledge
                    to create your own, fully functioning iOS app!`,
                    Learners: 63211,
                    Lessons: 54,
                    Quizzes: 623,
                    modalIsOpen: false,
                    setIsOpen:false,
                },

                {
                    id:"5",
                    languageName: "HTML",
                    about: `
                    This FREE course will teach you how to design a web page using HTML.
                    Complete a series of hands-on exercises and practice while writing real HTML code.`,
                    Learners: 18024,
                    Lessons: 32,
                    Quizzes: 962,
                    modalIsOpen: false,
                    setIsOpen:false,
                },

                {
                    id:"6",
                    languageName: "CSS",
                    about: `
                    Our CSS course will teach you how to control the style & layout of websites.
                    Complete a series of exercises and practice while filling out actual CSS templates.`,
                    Learners: 58932,
                    Lessons: 46,
                    Quizzes: 125,
                    modalIsOpen: false,
                    setIsOpen:false,

                }
            ]
        }
    }

    openModal(i) {
      const languageInfo = [...this.state.languageInfo];
      languageInfo[i] = {...languageInfo[i],setIsOpen: true,modalIsOpen: true}
        this.setState({languageInfo});
    }

    afterOpenModal() {
        // references are now sync'd and can be accessed.
        // subtitle.style.color = '#f00';
    }

    closeModal = (i)=>()=>{
      const languageInfo = [...this.state.languageInfo];
      languageInfo[i] = {...languageInfo[i],setIsOpen: false,modalIsOpen: false}
        this.setState({languageInfo});
    }

    render() {
        var subtitle;
        const resultsRender = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.languageInfo.length; i += 2) {
            resultsRender.push(
                <div key={i}>
                    {
                        this.state.languageInfo.slice(i, i + 2).map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={index}>    
                                        <div>
                                            <div>
                                                <div style={{marginRight: '25px'}}>
                                                    <img src={item.icon} alt=""/>
                                                </div>

                                                <div>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <h3>{item.languageName}</h3>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div>
                                                        <p style={{color: 'dimgrey'}}>
                                                            {item.about}
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                            <div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <button onClick={this.openModal.bind(this,index)}>Open Modal</button>
                                                    <Modal
                                                        isOpen={item.modalIsOpen}
                                                        onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal.bind(this)}
                                                        onRequestClose={this.closeModal(index)}
                                                        style={customStyles}
                                                        contentLabel="Example Modal"
                                                    >

                                                        <h2 ref={_subtitle => (subtitle = _subtitle)}>{item.languageName}</h2>
                                                        <button onClick={this.closeModal(index)}>close</button>
                                                        <div>I am a modal</div>
                                                        <form>
                                                            <input />
                                                            <button>tab navigation</button>
                                                            <button>stays</button>
                                                            <button>inside</button>
                                                            <button>the modal</button>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </Modal>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                        <div>
                                            <div>
                                                <p>Learners</p>
                                                <p>{item.Learners}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <p>Lessons</p>
                                                <p>{item.Lessons}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <p>Quizzes</p>
                                                <p>{item.Quizzes}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            }
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                {resultsRender}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо что обратили внимание, я использовал ваш вариант, но в таком случае работает только Python и JavaScript, остальное не работает, думаю что это из за цикла for (var i = 0; i < this.state.languageInfo.length; i += 2)